# How to filter by boolean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of booleans extracted and I would like to filter a dataframe from this in Pandas but it is returning no results.

Dataframe

```
  Account   mphone  rphone  BPHONE
0 14999201  3931812 8014059 9992222
1 12980801  4444444 3932929 4279999
2 9999999   3279999 4419999 3938888
```

Here are the series:

```
df['BPHONE'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list))

0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: BPHONE, dtype: bool

df['rphone'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list))

0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: rphone, dtype: bool
```

Now below, when I try to filter this, I am getting empty results:

```
df[(df['BPHONE'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list))) & (df['rphone'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list)))]

    Account mphone  rphone  BPHONE
```

Lastly, when I just use one column, it seems to match and filter by row and not column. Any advice here on how to correct this?

```
df[(df['BPHONE'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list)))]

  Account   mphone  rphone  BPHONE
1 12980801  4444444 3932929 4279999
```

I thought that this should just populate BPHONE along the column axis and not the row axis. How would I be able to filter this way?

The output wanted is the following:

```
Account  mphone rphone   BPHONE
14999201 3931812 8014059 np.nan
12980801 4444444 np.nan  4279999
99999999 3279999 4419999 np.nan
```

To explain this, rphone shows True, False, True, so only the True numbers should show. Under False it should not show, or show as NAN.

Comment: What you got is legit. Take a look at the result `df['BPHONE'].str.contains` and `df['rphone'].str.contains` -- do you see a row where both results are true?

Comment: Boolean masking operates on rows. You get no results, because `True False True` and `False True False` are mutually exclusive. You say you're trying to operate on the columns, can you provide a sample of your preferred output to make a [mcve] so we can better understand your problem?

Comment: What are you expecting to get? It seems it differs from the logic of the code you are sharing.

Comment: I added what is expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are expecting is not a filtered result, but conditionally replaced result.

```
condition = df['BPHONE'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list))
```

Use `np.where`

```
df['BPHONE'] = pd.np.where(condition, df['BPHONE'], pd.np.nan)
```

OR

```
df.loc[~condition, 'BPHONE'] = pd.np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

All filters you are applying are functioning correctly:

```
df['BPHONE'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list))   
0    False
1     True #Only this row will be retained 
2    False
```

The combined filter will return:

```
df[(df['BPHONE'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list))) & (df['rphone'].str.startswith(tuple(combined_list)))]

    First filter Second filter Combined filter
0          False          True           False #Not retained
1           True         False           False #Not retained
2          False          True           False #Not retained
```